# jQuery - "wait until ready"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, domready

I have this slider on my website:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

It works fine, but I don't like the way it loads (you can see list of the images with list dots before it is ready).

Is there a universal way of bypassing that? How to load the slider in the background so users don't see it UNTIL it's fully loaded (while it loads in the background I could display preloader.gif for example).

I was thinking about opacity: 0 & fading it after the slider in DOM, but maybe there's other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use the following pattern:

```
// assumes slider is hidden
var imgCount = $("#slider img").length;
var loadCount = 0;
$("#slider img").one("load", function() {
    loadCount++;
    if(loadCount === imgCount) {

        // show slider once all images have loaded
        showSlider();
    }
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});
```

Comment: this is a bit complex, I'll try it asap, but I was thinking about something more universal, that will work not only for this slider, but for any element. Maybe there's a library, jQuery plugin or something like that?

Comment: @Wordpressor - this is a general solution. `showSlider` could be anything at all. All this does it count the 'whatevers' as they load and once they're all done, do something.

Answer (score 0):

I would say apply css

```
.anythingSlider
{
    display:none;
}
```

and then change it with jQuery after the slider is loaded.